# Java object scope, referencing from a method

Tags: java, oop, object

I'm having some trouble getting scope right in my head.  I understand why the code below won't work, but I don't understand conceptually how I should be doing it.

```
public class Game {

    private String playerName = "";
    private int numberOfPegs = 0;
    private boolean gameRunning = "True";


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Game game = new Game();
        game.setupGame();
        game.playGame();
    }

    public void setupGame() {

        Display display = new Display();
        Code code = new Code();
        display.showGreeting();
        playerName = display.getUserInput("Enter your name: ");
        numberOfPegs = Integer.parseInt(display.getUserInput("How many pegs would you like?"));
        code.generateNewCode(numberOfPegs);
    }

    public void playGame() {
        String result = display.getGuess();

    }
}
```

I know why I can't call `display.getGuess()` from `playGame()`, it's because display is out of scope.  I don't understand how to do this correctly.  Do I create a new instance `Display()` for that method, that just doesn't feel like it's correct.   I feel like I'm missing a Object Oriented concept when it comes to working with multiple objects.

Comment: I think what's confusing for you is that the main method seems to belong to the Game class, but it's not really related to this class because it's static. It's only an entry point, and it could be defined in another class.

Comment: @Toilal Ok. That is part of it yes.  So where would main go, another class just for that?  Like I said, I feel like I'm missing part of a concept here!

Comment: Yes, you could create a Main class with only the static main method. But don't forget the import of Game class inside Main class :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the `display` as an instance field, and then initialize it in the `setupGame()` method.

```
private String playerName = "";
private int numberOfPegs = 0;
private boolean gameRunning = "True";
private Display display;


public static void main(String[] args) {

    Game game = new Game();
    game.setupGame();
    game.playGame();
}

public void setupGame() {

    display = new Display();
    Code code = new Code();
    display.showGreeting();
    playerName = display.getUserInput("Enter your name: ");
    numberOfPegs = Integer.parseInt(display.getUserInput("How many pegs would you like?"));
    code.generateNewCode(numberOfPegs);
}

public void playGame() {
    String result = display.getGuess();

}
```

There's no need to instantiate a member when you declare it. When you declare a member without instantiating, it takes its default value; `0` for numeric types, `false` for `boolean` and `null` for `Object` types. So in this case,

```
private int numberOfPegs = 0;
```

Would be the same as:

```
private int numberOfPegs;
```